# Source files installation problem in Adobe AIR

Tags: open-source, adobe, air

wonder why when I export my project to *.air and I install it on my computer.
I can see the source files in the software installed directory.

Should I choose something? or it's should be like this... because, why should I write softwares on adobe air if everyone can install the project and watch my codes?

I programmed on ajax, html, js..

I search on google and adobe air forums and I cant find and answer to my question.

I should like to any kind of help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By source, do you mean FLAs and AS files, or do you mean HTML and JS files? For HTML projects, yes, all your HTML and JS files will be visible to users in the packaged app. AIR basically just copies them to the user's installation directory and runs them. But for a Flash/Flex-based app, FLAs and AS files do not have to be distributed, only SWFs.

If FLAs and so on are showing up in your app directory, you'll want to change how you're exporting. The details depend on whether you're publishing from Flash, FB, or the command line, so if you can't find it please update your question with the details of what you're using.